# AWS SES + TLS: custom domain for mail servers

Tags: email, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When messing around with different mail hosting options I noticed a very aggravating pattern with my Android phone. Neither the built-in mail app nor the gmail app supported email auto-configuration.

When using most mail services such as Namecheap, Zoho, Rackspace, etc. this became a real issue. I would enter my email address and password then instead of it just working like magic, it would invariably fail as it attempted to set the mail server to **mail.example.com** instead of **mail.privateemail.com** or **smtp.zoho.com**

I can configure a CNAME entry for my domain to redirect to these servers and successfully connect to **mail.example.com**.... up until I try to enable secure e-mail (STARTTLS or TLS wrapper). When I do this the domain name on the certificate does not match up to the domain name I am using to access and the whole thing fails.

Of course setting up my own mail server *could* be an option, but it could take months or years for my IP address to build up enough reputation to not get auto-blocked by major providers like Gmail or Yahoo. This whole past month DreamHost has been unable to send emails to any address owned by AT&T, which has been nightmarish to get resolved. Not wanting an issue like that, I would like to go with a big name for e-mail hosting.

While looking into Amazon SES to see if it would be easy to set up, I noticed [this page on secure tunnels to AWS SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-secure-tunnel.html)

I'm not super familiar with mail servers and I honestly have no idea what I'm reading on this page. Like I can follow the steps to install and configure this program and run it, but it doesn't accurately say what the purpose is of doing this. Am I right in believing that this might solve my SSL issue and allow me to send mail to **mail.example.com** without any issues? If so, is there any additional setup that I will require which is not adequately explained by this article?

Comment: This article solves a different problem, allowing you to send mail from the system where you create the tunnel while the mail sending code on that system is such that *"your MTA does not support TLS Wrapper"*.  Even if you resolved this issue with a proxy (you could probably still use stunnel with a significantly different configuration to accomplish this), that only solves the "sending" problem.  There is no support for mailboxes (POP3/IMAP) on SES so there would be no way to actually receive email.  SES is primarily intended for use by *code* to send emails, not humans.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Are you certain you can't receive mail with SES? According to [their own promotional site](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/): "You can also use Amazon SES to receive messages and deliver them to an Amazon S3 bucket"

Comment: SES can indeed drop incoming email into an S3 bucket, but this is for messages you want to process with automation, as opposed to process with eyeballs; it doesn't mean you'd be able to actually check that mail on an android device.  There is no support in SES for the two common protocols devices use to check mailboxes and fetch received messages, POP3 and IMAP4.